# Optimize python program to parse two large files at the same time

Tags: python, optimization, cluster-computing, large-data, data-processing

I am trying to parse two large files with Python3 at the same time. As shown here:

```py
dict = {}
row = {}
with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
  zipped = zip(f1, f2)
  for line_f1, line_f2 in zipped:
    # parse the lines and save the line information in a dictionary 
    row = {"ID_1":line_f1[0], "ID_2":line_f2[0], ...}

    # This process takes roughly 0.0005s each time
    # it parses each pair of lines at once and returns an output
    # it doesn't depend on previous lines or lines after
    output = process(row) 

    # output is a string, add it to dict
    if output in dict:
       dict[output] += 1
    else:
       dict[output] = 1
return dict
```

When I tested the above code with two smaller text files (30,000 lines each, file size = 13M) and it takes roughly 150s to finish the loop.

When I tested with two large text files (9,000,000 lines each, file size = 3.8G) without the process step in the loop it takes roughly 670s.

When I tested with the same two large text files with the process step. I timed that for every 10,000 items it will take roughly 60s. The time didn't grow when the number of iterations gets large.

However, when I submit this job to a shared cluster it takes more than 36 hours for one pair of large files to finish processing. I am trying to figure out if there is any other way to process the files so it can be faster. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you split your files into chunks, you could process these chunks in parallel, using more than one CPU core. Afterwards, you just need to sum up the results of all jobs.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Thanks! That's something I was thinking about. But it would mess up the structure of my code a lot. I guess I would have to do that if no other improvements are available.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hypothesis, but your process could be wasting its allocated CPU slot every time it triggers an I/O to get a pair of lines.  You could try reading groups of lines at a time and processing in chunks so you can make the most of each CPU time slot you get on the shared cluster.

```
from collections import deque
chunkSize = 1000000 # number of characters in each chunk (you will need to adjust this)
chunk1    = deque([""]) #buffered lines from 1st file
chunk2    = deque([""]) #buffered lines from 2nd file
with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
    while chunk1 and chunk2:
        line_f1 = chunk1.popleft()
        if not chunk1:
            line_f1,*more = (line_f1+file1.read(chunkSize)).split("\n")
            chunk1.extend(more)
        line_f2 = chunk2.popleft()
        if not chunk2:
            line_f2,*more = (line_f2+file2.read(chunkSize)).split("\n")
            chunk2.extend(more)
        # process line_f1, line_f2
        ....
```

The way this works is by reading a chunk of characters (which must be larger than your longest line) and breaking it down into lines.  The lines are placed in a queue for processing.

Because the chunksize is expressed in number of characters, the last line in the queue may be incomplete.

To ensure that lines are complete before being processed, another chunk is read when we get to the last line in the queue.  The additional characters are added to the end of the incomplete line and the line splitting is performed on the combined string.  Because we concatenated the last (incomplete) line, the `.split("\n")` function always applies to a chunk of text that begins at a line boundary.

The process continues with the (now completed) last line and the rest of the lines are added to the queue.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try for sure. I have a question that in this case if the chunkSize is the number of characters in each chunk, does that mean if I have a fixed size for all the files and it would require that all the lines are the same in length? In other words, is there going to be half a line ended up in `line_f1` or `line_f2` if the chunk size is fixed? I think I don't fully understand how it works within `if not chunk1:`

Comment: No. the way the chunking is done in my example, you only need to have the same number of lines. Line boundaries are managed by the `line_f1,*more = (line_f1+file1.read(chunkSize)).split("\n")` statement